# Question about Rudin's PMA

Tags: real-analysis

Theorem 3.20(a): If $p>0$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^p} = 0$

Proof: Take $n > (1/ \epsilon)^{1/p}$.

What does the author mean by "the archimedean property of the real number system is used here."

Comment: That property is spelled out explicitly early on in the book, maybe in chapter 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PMA Chapter 1, Theorem 1.20:

(a) If $x\in R$, $y\in R$, and $x>0$, then there is a positive integer $n$ such that $nx>y$.

Rudin says: "Part (a) is usually referred to as the *archimedean property* of $R$." The proof of your 3.20(a) is applying the archimedean property with $x:=\epsilon^{1/p}$ and $y=1$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks.